# How to pass foreign key in django

Tags: django

I have created a form for feedback having model

```
    feedbackid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    courseid = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    submitdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    teacherid = models.ForeignKey('schoolTeacher', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    studentid = models.ForeignKey('Student', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    option = [('Good','Good'),('Average','Average'),('Bad','Bad')]
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=option, default='none')
```

And the input is taken through form

```
<form action="/studentFeedBack/" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
          
          <label for="studentid">Student Id</label>
          <input type="number" name="studentid"><br><br>

          <label for="courseid">Course Id</label>
          <input type="number" name="courseid"><br><br>

          <label for="teacherid">Teacher Id</label>
          <input type="number" name="teacherid"><br><br>


          <label for="description" >Feedback</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="description"></textarea><br><br>

          <label for="rating">Rating</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="Good" name="rating" value="Good">
          <label for="Good">Good</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="Average" name="rating" value="Average">
          <label for="Average">Average</label><br>
          <input type="radio" id="Bad" name="rating" value="Bad">
          <label for="Bad">Bad</label><br><br>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
    </form>
```

This form has three foreign keys from the following tables

```
class Course(models.Model):
    courseid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    coursedescription = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    coursename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    userid = models.IntegerField()
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    videolink = models.FileField(default='default_link')
    # roleid = models.ForeignKey(RoleName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    createddate = models.DateTimeField()
    imagelink = models.URLField(default='default_link')
    duration = models.DateTimeField()
    longdes = models.TextField()
    coursetype = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    # classid = models.ForeignKey(TblClass, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assignto = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    status = models.BinaryField()

    def _str_(self):
        return self.coursename


class schoolTeacher(models.Model):
    teacherid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField()
    contact = models.IntegerField()
    passowrd = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg')
    regno = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    joiningdate = models.DateTimeField()

    def _str_(self):
        return self.name


class Student(models.Model):
    studentid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    regno = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    contactno = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    registrationdate = models.DateTimeField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    imagepath = models.ImageField(max_length=100, default='default.jpg')
    sectionid = models.IntegerField()

    def _str_(self):
        return self.name
```

Now my views.py has

```
def studentFeedBack(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        studentid = request.POST.get("studentid")
        courseid = request.POST.get("courseid")
        teacherid = request.POST.get("teacherid")
        description = request.POST.get("description")
        rating = request.POST.get("rating")
        instance = studentFeedBack( courseid=courseid,  description=description, studentid=studentid, teacherid=teacherid, rating=rating )
        instance.save()


    return render(request, 'forms/studentFeedBack.html', {'title' : 'ComplaintForm'})
```

This is giving error on browser when form is submitted

```
TypeError at /studentFeedBack/
studentFeedBack() got an unexpected keyword argument 'courseid'
```

This is most probably because this is not how you pass an instance to a model having foreign key. So how should I pass the foreign keys in views?

Comment: You have not connected your form to ```html```. This is is how you should do it ```<form action="/studentFeedBack/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>```

Comment: I have added it. Please check the second code of block

Comment: you defined that function with one argument, and based on post request. so in templates it doesn't expect any *args **kwargs.

Comment: @Mahdi Firouzjah how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

the syntax in complete version is similar to:

```
{% url 'app_name:url_name' *args **kwargs %}?get_method_keys=true
```

but in your case it doesn't need all of the parameters.
maybe `{% url 'app_name:url_name' %}` or `{% url 'url_name' %}`. but you need to refer to Django docs for more.

Answer (score 0):

Use django-widget-tweaks.

Create a form at forms.py

Then include this form into your studentFeedBack view.

After install django-widget-tweaks include it on your html page with {% load widget_tweaks %}

Then render your courseid input with this code:

```
{% render_field form.courseid class="form-control" %}
```